# How to count values when columns have same values?

Tags: python

I am have a quick question,

```
|index|  column1 column2
 
 1           A       A      
 2           C       A       
 3           D       D        
 4           B       C
```

if I have a matrix like above, I would like to count values having the same things.

So in here, it would be row 1(A,A), 3(D,D). So count values will be 2.

How do I write code for getting the values? I would like to use 'enumerate' function.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
grouped_data = [[index+1, (row[1], row[2])] for index, row in enumerate(matrix)]
```